# Why is reading a settings property value making a SettingsPropertyValue object dirty?

Tags: c#, settingsprovider

While implementing a custom settings provider I noticed that accessing a setting property's value changes its `IsDirty` flag to `true`.

```
// Arrange
var property = new SettingsProperty("property1")
{
    PropertyType = typeof(Color),
    DefaultValue = "Green"
};

// Act
var result = new SettingsPropertyValue(property);

// Assert
Assert.That(result.IsDirty, Is.False);
Assert.That(result.PropertyValue, Is.EqualTo(Color.Green));
Assert.That(result.IsDirty, Is.False); // <-- Assertion fails
```

Reflector gives me an answer to the question why the `PropertyValue` getter is behaving like this - it contains a statement like the following:

```
if (_Value != null && !Property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && !(_Value is string) && !(_Value is DateTime))
{
    _UsingDefaultValue = false;
    _ChangedSinceLastSerialized = true;
    _IsDirty = true;
}
```

Can anybody shed some light on this at first glance strange behavior?

Comment: This is the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/configuration/SettingsPropertyValue.cs,efd6a6f498ec4a74,references

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingspropertyvalue.isdirty.aspx) states that this is to account for any potential side effects of accessing the value when it is a complex type, as well as mutating the value without reassigning the value (for example when modifying the items in a list):

> The IsDirty property is set to **true** under the following conditions:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. The value contained in the SettingsPropertyValue object is accessed, and the value is not a string or a primitive type such as **int**, **float**, **real**, or **DateTime**. When the value managed by a SettingsPropertyValue object is a complex type (for example an ArrayList), there is no way for a SettingsPropertyValue object to detect when changes have been made. As a result, the SettingsPropertyValue object pessimistically assumes that a complex type is dirty once it has been accessed from the PropertyValue property.